# Java CXF WS Client - gZip HTTP REQUEST HEADER being ignored

Tags: java, http-headers, cxf

I am trying to set/request gZip in HTTP REQUEST HEADERS inside my Java CXF WS Client BUT for some reason its being IGNORED. I don't get back gZipped response. Here is how I am trying to set. I am using Apache CXF 2.3.2. What am I missing?

```
public class LoggerXML implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {
    private String uniqueIdentifier;
    private String sessionId;

    public LoggerXML(String sessionId, String uniqueIdentifier) {
        this.sessionId = sessionId;
        this.uniqueIdentifier = uniqueIdentifier;
    }

    protected final void setLogStream(PrintStream ps) {
      //  out = ps;
    }

    public void init(Map c) {
        uniqueIdentifier = "";
    }

    public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
        return null;
    }

    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext smc) {

        Boolean outboundProperty = (Boolean)
        smc.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);
        if(outboundProperty){
            // Creating HTTP headers & setting gZip.
            Map<String, List<String>> headers = (Map<String, 
                                        List<String>>) smc.get(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS);
            if(headers == null){
                //System.out.println("LoggerXML.handleMessage: headers = null");
                headers = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();  
            }
            // Add HTTP headers to the web service request
            headers.put("Accept-Encoding", Collections.singletonList("gzip,deflate"));
            //headers.put("Content-Encoding", Collections.singletonList("gzip"));
            //headers.put("Accept-Encoding", Collections.singletonList("gzip"));

            smc.put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, headers);
            //smc.put("org.apache.cxf.transport.common.gzip.GZIPOutInterceptor.UseGzip","YES");

        }

        return true;
    }

    public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext smc) {
        return true;
    }

    // nothing to clean up
    public void close(MessageContext messageContext) {
    }

    // nothing to clean up
    public void destroy() {
    }

// Other Methods....

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me

```
    // Get the underlying Client object from the proxy object of service interface
Client proxy = ClientProxy.getClient(stub);

   // Creating HTTP headers
Map<String, List<String>> headers = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
headers.put("Accept-Encoding", Arrays.asList("gzip"));

    // Add HTTP headers to the web service request
proxy.getRequestContext().put(Message.PROTOCOL_HEADERS, headers);
```

Refer:http://singztechmusings.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/apache-cxf-how-to-add-custom-http-headers-to-a-web-service-request/